# Android device height is not accurate on titanium mobile

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, titanium, titanium-mobile

We are developing a mobile app for `android`, `ios` and `mobile` web using `Titanium`. We need the exact device height on some of our functionalities. We used `Ti.Platform.DisplayCaps.platformHeight` to get the device height and it is working just fine on ios and mobileweb. But on android, it returns a very huge number. It is returning 1059, which very big number. When we do a view for example with `height : 400`, it is already 60% of the screen.

Your help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just come across the same "thing" in my app the problem is that the function `Ti.Platform.DisplayCaps.platformHeight` on android returns the value in pixel but in iOs is Dpi.

as workaround for this discrepancy I've put thi in my app:

```
if (osname == 'android')
{
    densityMultiplier = Ti.Platform.displayCaps.logicalDensityFactor;
}
if (osname == 'iphone')
{
    densityMultiplier = 1;
}
```

and to set the hight of the view:

```
$.myView.setHight(newHight * densityMultiplier)
```

I hope this is helpful.

Jaba81